# Finding stock numbers for products on magento sites

Tags: stock, inventory

to start this question, i'd like to say that i'm a complete noob and dont really know how to read code. i'd just like to know how to find inventory/stock numbers on certain products on magento sites, such as ENDclothing.com. could anyone help me learn how to use this code so that i can find these values? thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You will get stock number for certain product

```
    $productId='1';
    $stock = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($productId);
    echo $stock->getQty();
```

Answer (score 0):

They use structured data, so there's a meta tag with itemprop="sku" that will give you the sku. You can use google's structured data explorer if that's easier. https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/u/0/#url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.endclothing.com%2Fgb%2Fstone-island-nylon-metal-shirt-jacket-6515-10112-v0029.html